# Need to get instanceName as a String from a var in Swift

Tags: swift

Suppose I have the following line of code.

```
var instanceName = "someString"
```

How would I get the name of the instance in a String format so I can use that as a key to store the var in NSUserDefaults?
So in the above case, I am looking to get "instanceName" from instanceName...

Follow-up question:
How do I get back to the variable contents by using a string. E.g. `"instanceName"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all variables from class instance by using `class_copyIvarList` **(as I know Swift doesn't support optional vars)**, loop over them and get names.

```
var aClass : AnyClass? = self.dynamicType
var propertiesCount : CUnsignedInt = 0
let propertiesInAClass : UnsafeMutablePointer<Ivar> = class_copyIvarList(aClass, &propertiesCount)   

for var i = 0; i < Int(propertiesCount); i++ {                                
  var propName:String = NSString(CString: ivar_getName(propertiesInAClass[Int(i)]), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)  
}//for
```

---

**Playground**

```
class Myclass{

    var myInteger:Int = 1
    var myBoolean:Bool = false
    var myString:String = "heyStr"

    func printValues(){
      var aClass : AnyClass? = self.dynamicType
      var propertiesCount : CUnsignedInt = 0
      let propertiesInAClass : UnsafeMutablePointer<Ivar> = class_copyIvarList(aClass, &propertiesCount)        

      for var i = 0; i < Int(propertiesCount); i++ {
        var propName:String = NSString(CString: ivar_getName(propertiesInAClass[Int(i)]), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        println(propName)
     }//for
    }       
}

var mc:Myclass = Myclass()
mc.printValues()
```

Output:

```
myInteger
myBoolean
myString
```

---

**[EDIT 1]**

`Ivar` refers to Objective-C runtime:

```
/// An opaque type that represents an instance variable.
typealias Ivar = COpaquePointer
```

---

**[EDIT 2]**

If you interesting to get values also do two things:

- inherit your cass from `NSObject` a.e. `class Myclass:NSObject{..}`
- `var propValue : AnyObject! = self.valueForKey(propName)`

Btw, if you want to store them into some Dictionary, you need 1st check their type. Because you have `propValue` defined as `AnyObject`

Comment: Would you perhaps also know how to get back to the var using the propName? I tried "var value: AnyObject = object_getIvar(self, class_getInstanceVariable(self.dynamicType, propName))" But that gives me a bad access...

Comment: @P5ycH0 do you want to get value by name?

Comment: Yeah, You've gave me the solution to get the names of ivars. Now all I need is to get the value for each propName I find, so I can store it by it's propName key in userdefaults. I am trying "var value: AnyObject = object_getIvar(aClass, class_getInstanceVariable(aClass!, propName))" now, and I see the value I need in the debugger, but still get an BAD ACCESS.... I am so close to the solution.....

Comment: @P5ycH0 I added 2nd EDIT, but you must change your question, maybe it good for you but other developers can find my answer not so pure on your question. Please, change it respectively.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60675/discussion-between-p5ych0-and-maxim-shoustin).